# specific date within select expert

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

My report is scheduled to automatically run on a custom calender which is: 
1st of the month to the 7th 
8st of the month to the 14th
15th of the month to the 22nd
23rd of the month to the last day of the month

What i am trying to do basically is when the report is run, select the dates between current day -7 to current day -1 unless its the last day of the month and then i want it to run it from the 22nd of the last month to the last day of the last month. i hope this makes sense.
Thanks
Houlahan

Comment: When you say "select the dates" do you mean "select the records with those dates" or do you mean you want to display those dates on the report?

Comment: sorry i want to select records with those dates

Comment: Ok so are you executing a stored procedure, running a SQL command? Were you planning on using a Selection Forumula? What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using BusinessObjects Entprise, here's the approach that I would take:

Two recurring (scheduled) instances.

Instance 1:

- scheduled to run 'Daily' (ignore the report that is generated on the last day of the month)
- add the following to the instance's filter:

  AND {TABLE.DATE_FIELD} IN (DateDate - 7) TO (DataDate - 1)

Instance 2:

- scheduled to run 'Last Day of Month'
- add the following to the instance's filter:

  AND {TABLE.DATE_FIELD} IN Date(Year((Date(Year(DataDate), Month(DateDate), 1) - 1)), Month((Date(Year(DataDate), Month(DateDate), 1) - 1)), 22) TO (Date(Year(DataDate), Month(DateDate), 1) - 1)